# MySQL insert statement over remote server is extremely slow. How can I speed it up?

Tags: performance-tuning, sql, insert

I need to insert values to a remote MySQL server. However it is extremely slow compared to a local MySQL server.

This is my timing for the local MySQL server

```
Needs["DatabaseLink`"]

conn = OpenSQLConnection[
   JDBC["MySQL(Connector/J)", 
    "localhost/schema"], "Username" -> "root", 
   "Password" -> "pass"];

list = Table[{SQLDateTime[DateList@{2015, 1, 1, 1, 1, i}], i}, {i, 1, 
    100}];

SQLInsert[conn, "albedometer", {"dateTime", "volts"},
   list]; // AbsoluteTiming

{0.045335, Null}
```

This is my timing for the remote MySQL server

```
conn1 = OpenSQLConnection[
   JDBC["MySQL(Connector/J)", 
    "remoteServer/schema"], 
   "Username" -> "server", "Password" -> "server"];


list = Table[{SQLDateTime[DateList@{2015, 1, 1, 1, 1, i}], i}, {i, 1, 
    100}];

SQLInsert[conn1, "albedometer", {"dateTime", "volts"},
   list]; // AbsoluteTiming

{117.437, Null}
```

As you can see the difference is huge 0.04 vs 117 seconds. 
It is just plain impossible to work with such an small insert speed.

How could I speed this up?

Comment: What is the ping between your computer and the remote server?

Comment: @Edmund, it is about 300 ms. But I dont think that's the issue since the same procedure with python + sqlalchemy does the insert in under a second

Comment: Try using a stored procedure for the update. I only upsert through sprocs to control access (SQL Server). I don't have any issues with repeated calls wrapped in a transaction on the connection. Perhaps the direct table bit has some issues. Or try wrapping the updates in a transaction on the connection.  That might help. http://reference.wolfram.com/language/DatabaseLink/tutorial/Transactions.html

Comment: I am pretty sure that by playing with SQLInsert's "BatchSize" option, you can get better performance. http://reference.wolfram.com/language/DatabaseLink/ref/SQLInsert.html

Answer (score 5):

So finally I decided to create a BatchInsert[] functions that is 100 times faster than SQLInsert[]. This is the code:

```
BatchInsert[con_, tableName_, columns_, data_, max_:100]:=
    Module[{
      dataSplit, str, res
    },


      dataSplit = Partition[data, UpTo[max]];
      SQLBeginTransaction[con];
      res = InsertSingle[#, con, columns, tableName] & /@ dataSplit;
      res = Total@res;
      If[res === Length@data,
        SQLCommitTransaction[con];
        True
        ,
        SQLRollbackTransaction[con];
        $Failed
      ]

    ];

InsertSingle[data_, con_, cols_, tableName_] :=
    Module[{ll, str},
      ll = StringJoin@
          Riffle[Table[{"(",
            Sequence @@ Riffle[Table["?", Length@cols], ","],
            ")\n"},
            Length@data], ","];

      str =
          StringTemplate["INSERT INTO `tab` (`cols`) VALUES `ll`"]@
              Association@{
                "cols" -> StringJoin[Riffle[cols, ","]],
                "ll" -> ll,
                "tab" -> tableName

              };

      SQLExecute[con,
    str,
    Flatten@data,
    "JavaBatching" -> False
  ]
];
```

You can compare both functions with:

```
Map[AbsoluteTiming[#[con,tb,col,data];]&,{BatchInsert,SQLInsert}]
```

Comment: I used code and ideas from http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/73444/slow-work-of-sqlinsert-with-ms-sql-server-in-v10

Comment: I tested [my answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/73476/2266) using `"JavaBatching"->False,"BatchSize"-> 1000` with mySQL, and it don't works as in SQLServer. +1